# Error when load 3rd party libraries in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using the blip-chat-widget library to load in app that uses NextJS, apparently everything works in the development environment, but in the build I have the following error:

```
Cannot find the name 'BlipChat'
```

I'm implementing the library in `_app.tsx` using the `next/script` that was included in Next 11

This is the part of the code that renders the chat:

```
import Script from 'next/script';  


render(): JSX.Element {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Layout>
        <ErrorBoundary fallback={<ErrorPage />}>
          <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </QueryClientProvider>
        </ErrorBoundary>
        
       
         <Script
          src="https://unpkg.com/blip-chat-widget@1.9.1"
          onLoad={() => {
            const blipClient = new BlipChat();

            blipClient
              .withAppKey('app_key')
              .withButton({ color: '#FFCC00' })
              .build();
          }}
        />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
```

I'm following what the documentation says to implement, but I don't know what to do to stop with the error in `new BlipChat()`. Does anyone know how I can resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)? That's a TypeScript error because `BlipChat` isn't declared  as a property in the `window` global. Declaring the property then using it as `new window.BlipChat()` should make the error go away.