# How to tell the compiler about window.Cypress in .tsx files?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm building an app with Cypress and TypeScript.

I have the following code, which slightly alters the behaviour of the Magic SDK based on whether it runs inside of an E2E tests, or not:

```
const magic = new Magic(window.ENV.MAGIC_PUBLISHABLE_KEY, {
  testMode: Boolean(window.Cypress),
});
```

TypeScript complains about `window.Cypress` and says:

```
Property 'Cypress' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

How can I tell TypeScript about `Cypress`? Basically I need something like this:

```
type Window = {
  Cypress?: Cypress; // Where Cypress is the Cypress namespace
}
```

I found [this answer](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3924) (amongst others) in Google but I couldn't see how that would solve this specific issue.

**EDIT:**

The question Tobias linked in a comment is different because if you do:

```
declare global {
  Cypress: Cypress;
}
```

TypeScript complains that:

```
Unexpected labeled statement.
```

And when you do:

```
declare global {
  var Cypress: Cypress;
}
```

TypeScript complains that:

```
Cannot augment module 'Cypress' with value exports because it resolves to a non-module entity.
```

I couldn't find the code on Github, but in my `node_modules` it lives here:

[image]

So the solutions from the suggested answer won't work, because Cypress is a namespace, and not a type - though to solve this question you probably need it to be a type.

**EDIT 2:**

Fody's answer doesn't work, either.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Comment: If the above question/answer doesn't help, could you include why it doesn't or any trouble you have implementing the solutions?

Comment: @catgirlkelly I just did! :) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some playing around the following seems to work:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Cypress?: Cypress.Cypress;
  }
}

if (window.Cypress) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern used by Gleb Bahmutov in his slides is

```js
interface Window {
  Cypress? : any    // don't really need strict type here
}

if (window.Cypress) {   
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! Typesafety would be awesome, I mean why use TypeScript otherwise? But anyways, this doesn't work. Will attach screenshot in the question :)

Comment: I don't get that - looks like it's related to the error above on `Window`. What is that error?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the namespace to a declared constant and export it:

```
declare global {
  export declare const Cypress: Cypress;
}
```

Not 100% sure if this works, things with ambient type declarations are always a bit finnicky.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, this gives three errors: `A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.`, `Cannot augment module 'Cypress' with value exports because it resolves to a non-module entity.` and `Cannot use namespace 'Cypress' as a type.`.

Comment: Oh it's a namespace... Totally missed that.