# How do I add a property to window and make it globally available?

Tags: typescript

In my code below, I cannot remove `window` from `globalStorage` or I get the error:

> "cannot find name 'globalStorage'. Did you mean 'GlobalStorage'?"

Is there not a way to add properties to `Window` and make them available in the global scope without having to reference `window`? I'm trying to make this work like `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. Having to include `window` makes it less appealing.

```
declare global {
    interface Window { globalStorage: GlobalStorage; }
}

window.globalStorage = new GlobalStorage();

export function loadGlobal<TData>(key: string, defaultValue: TData): TData;
export function loadGlobal<TData>(key: string): TData | undefined;
export function loadGlobal<TData>(key: string, defaultValue?: TData) {
    return load(window.globalStorage, key, defaultValue);
}

export function saveGlobal<TData>(key: string, data: TData) {
   return save(window.globalStorage, key, data);
}

export function hasKeyGlobal(key: string) {
    return hasKey(window.globalStorage, key);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put ```globalStorage: GlobalStorage``` inside ```declare global``` not inside ```interface Windows```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your properties inside global namespace to extend globalThis:

```
declare global {     
    let foo: string; 
    let bar: number;
    globalStorage:  GlobalStorage;
}
```

Comment: At first, I was going to say, that's what I did
, but then it hit me that it is absolutely not what I did.