# TypeScript cannot find name of window property in Playwright evaluate callback

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am using Typescript with Playwright. I have this code to evaluate JavaScript in the browser:

```
const CSRFToken = await this.page.evaluate(() => {
  return ACC.config.CSRFToken;
});
```

But I get an error: `Cannot find name 'ACC'.ts(2304)`.

`ACC.config.CSRFToken` is something that exists on my page in the `script` tag of the DOM.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is `ACC` a property on the `window` object? If so, perhaps you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript

Comment: @NicholasTower it is in my script tag of the page, not sure if that qualifies as a property of the window object. Do you think it is part of the window object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable ACC in your typescript file and use that variable like following.

```
declare const ACC: any;
const CSRFToken = await this.page.evaluate(() => {
    return ACC.config.CSRFToken;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works nicely for this particular case is to pass a string as the function body:

```js
const CSRFToken = await this.page.evaluate("ACC.config.CSRFToken");
```