# Extending window interface through local `d.ts` file

Tags: typescript

Let me start by saying I've read the workarounds that's described here: [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

I'm essentially trying to do the same thing, but the below configuration on a MacOS device, I'm getting compilation failures.

> node -v ==> v.18.12.0

Dependencies from the `package.json` file.

```js
"dependencies": {
   "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
   "jest": "^29.2.2",
   "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
   "typescript": "^4.8.4"
}
```

`tsconfig.json` file

```js
{
   "files": ["src/index.ts"],
   "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "target": "ES6",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "src/types"]
    }
}
```

What I have in the /src/types:

```js
// index.d.ts
export {};

declare global {
   interface Window {
       Office: any;
   }
}
```

And from the source files, I'm getting the error below:

> Property `Office` does not exit on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.

**Weird thing is, Jest files are seeing the types, in fact I can run tests. It's only the actual source files which contain the logic that's failing to pick up the types.**

Comment: Remove the `export {}` as it makes it *not* an ambient declaration file.

Comment: If I remove that, I receive this: `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.ts(2669)`