# How to merge multiple global.d.ts with third party lib

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, webpack, global-variables

I have attached 2 libs with the same global obj names.

```
 <script src="http://url-to-third-party-lib.com/sdk1"></script>
 <script src="http://url-to-my-lib.com/sdk2"></script>
```

1. lib:
   Access by `window.DummyGlobalObject.init();`
2. lib: 
   Access by:

```
var PortalInstance = window.DummyGlobalObject.Instance;
var someInputOptions = { ... }
var dummyobj = new PortalInstance(someInputOptions);
```

I've included two libs that overwrite each other.
We can see two global objects with the same `window.DummyGlobalObject`

**Example**:

Actually i have an access to both libs but first is deployed via CDN.
`<script src="http://url-to-third-party-lib.com/sdk1"></script>`

***First lib body:***

For building this i am using webpack and i want to find out some solution about merging both if both exist.
**Maybe there is webpack plugin/hack that is able to handle this problem (merging both libs).**

**`Webpack.config.js`**

```
module.exports = function (x, env) {
    return {
        target: 'web',
        mode: 'development',
        entry: {
            Instance: './src/DummyGlobalScript.ts',
        },
        node: {
            global: true,
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve('./dist'),
            filename: '[name].js',
            sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
            library: 'DummyGlobalObject', // <------- GLOBAL
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        },
        devtool: false,
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'less-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new TerserJSPlugin({}), 
                new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
            ],
        },
    };
};
```

***Second lib body definition:***

```
export interface SomeGlobalOptions {
    name: string;
    url: string;
}
```

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        DummyGlobalObject: SomeGlobalOptions;
    }
    const DummyGlobalObject: SomeGlobalOptions;
}
```

The question how to use both libs if both scripts attached on website? (by merging both ???)

```
/// some pseudocode
if(window.DummyGlobalObject !== undefined){
   /// ????????? acutally don't have idea...
   Object.assign(window.DummyGlobalObject, ??????????????)
}
```

Comment: Please try to clarify the question. It isn't quite clear what is your problem.

You have `typescript` in tags. Does your problem relate to types or ts compiler?
It isn't clear what was meant by `Access by` section
Error messages and/or expected results would also help

Comment: Main problem is that i want to run app with 2 scripts that have the same global name `window.DummyGlobalObject`. Should i merge both objects? How to handle it via webpack? Maybe it possible to handle it by `declare glabal` modification.
I found similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/30740935/5358061