# Extend AudioContext in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, extend

I would like to extend (in OOP terms) the built-in [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) class in TypeScript:

```
class LiveAudioContext extends AudioContext {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public setPlaybackRate(rate: number) {
        console.log(`Set rate to ${rate}.`);
    }
}
```

This is valid TypeScript, accepted by both the compiler and IntelliSense. At runtime however, I get a `TypeError`, for which Chrome adds the following error message as well:

```
var liveCtx = new LiveAudioContext();
```

> Failed to construct 'AudioContext': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Fair enough, I know how it would be possible to solve the issue in the [compiled Javascript output](https://jsfiddle.net/hbu3gh6j/1/). However, having to manually fix an error caused by the compiler after each build is just unsuitable for production use.

How could I accomplish this extension correctly, so that it is functional in the compiled output as well, and off-the-shelf?

---

Edit: of course, creating a wrapper class that effectively redefines every single method and property works, but I find it to be smelling -- more like, *stinking*, and badly -- from an architectural point of view:

```
class LiveAudioContext {
    private internalContext: AudioContext;

    public createBuffer() {
        return this.internalContext.createBuffer.apply(this.internalContext, arguments);
    }

    public createBufferSource() {
        return this.internalContext.createBufferSource.apply(this.internalContext, arguments);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Some built-ins are not extensible.  I believe the [Proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is meant to handle this use case, but that relegates you to a more recent browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following question provides a good solution: [How to handle warnings for proprietary/custom properties of built-in objects in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703266/how-to-handle-warnings-for-proprietary-custom-properties-of-built-in-objects-in)

Essentially you extend the existing interface, and apply your new methods directly on the browser's objects.