# Google Tag Manager dataLayer Type Error: ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-analytics, webpack, google-tag-manager

Can someone explain to me why

```
(<any>window).dataLayer2 = (<any>window).dataLayer2 || [];
```

Does not throw an error and

```
(<any>window).dataLayer = (<any>window).dataLayer || [];
```

Does throw a type error: "Error: Can't resolve 'dataLayer'"

I need to be able to get access to the google analytics global variable and am not sure why this doesn’t work or how to expose it for ES6.

I'm using webpack and typescript and have added it to my index.ejs as follows:

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-okoko" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
   (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
   new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
   })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ookok');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using TypeScript 2.9.2

typings.d.ts

```
interface Window { dataLayer: any; }
```

app.ts

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({...});
```

See these other answers for more info:

[How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

[How to handle warnings for proprietary/custom properties of built-in objects in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703266/how-to-handle-warnings-for-proprietary-custom-properties-of-built-in-objects-in/12703866#12703866)