# Extending javascript "class" (object)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript

I'm using a javascript library (pixi.js to be specific) and I'm trying to extend one of their classes in typescript. However, trying to extend the class like below will yield an error.

```
module tilesystem {

    declare var PIXI;
    // Class
    export class Tilegrid PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer
    {
        public layers : number= layers;
        public rows : number= rows;
        public columns : number = columns;
        public tilesize : number = tilesize;
        // Constructor
        constructor(layers, columns, rows, tilesize, stage, texture)
        {
            super( );
           //implementation
        }
    }

    //Tilegrid.constructor = Tilegrid;
    Tilegrid.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer.prototype);

}
```

error :

> Base type 'any' lacks an implementation.

I would be fine with just extending it the ugly javascript way, but that then it will still complain about not know it's super methods.

```
module tilesystem {

    declare var PIXI;
    // Class
    export class Tilegrid
    {
        public layers : number= layers;
        public rows : number= rows;
        public columns : number = columns;
        public tilesize : number = tilesize;
        // Constructor
        constructor(layers, columns, rows, tilesize, stage, texture)
        {
            **PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer.call(this);**
           *this.addChild( new Tile() );* //throws an error, because addChild is not known
        }
    }

    **Tilegrid.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer.prototype);**

}
```

[How to extend native JavaScript array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000645/how-to-extend-native-javascipt-array-in-typescript)
I know that this anwser suggest using an interface, but I would really like to prevent writing wrappers. 
I would much rather find a way to either supress the error when using super methods, or somehow get the type info from the javascript class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first block of code worked for me with just a couple minor changes.

Here's what I did: downloaded the Pixi lib from https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/blob/master/bin/pixi.dev.js ; downloaded a declaration file from https://github.com/xperiments/Pulsar/blob/master/src/libs/pixi.d.ts ; removed `declare var PIXI;` from the source, added the keyword `extends` and an alert to know it works so it looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="pixi.d.ts" />

module tilesystem {
    export class Tilegrid extends PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer {
        public layers: number = layers;
        public rows: number = rows;
        public columns: number = columns;
        public tilesize: number = tilesize;
        constructor(layers, columns, rows, tilesize, stage, texture) {
            super();
            alert("I ran");
        }
    }
}

var x = new tilesystem.Tilegrid(null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Then I tested it in an html file where pixi.js is included *before* the custom code like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="pixi.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="output.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if your problem is in your lack in referencing a declaration file, the missing extends keyword, or how your include js files in your html but something in those steps should help.

Comment: I had no idea pixi had the declaration file. I still sort off hate being dependant on the developer supplying one though.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way around that.  Fortunately you can make your own and there are repos where people have done just that.