# how to extends and override array methods in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, overriding, extends

now I want to implement an array proxy. here's my code

```
class ArrayProxy<T> extends Array<T> {

    constructor(data: T[]) {
        super(...data);
    }

    push(...items: T[]): number {
        var res = super.push(...items);
        console.log("push invoked!");
        // some code to do extra operation.
        return res;
    }
}

var foo = new ArrayProxy(["aa","bb"]);
foo.push("cc");
```

it seems that my override push methods was not invoked. and the foo variable is instance of Array other than ArrayProxy.
**my typescript version:2.3.2**
tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "outFile": "js/test.js"
    }
}
```

**MyTest**
i looked for some solution but failed.

```
class MyNewArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    getFirst() {
        return this[0];
    }
}

var myArray = new MyNewArray<string>();
myArray.push("First Element");
console.log(myArray.getFirst()); // "First Element"
```

from [David Sherret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000645/how-to-extend-native-javascript-array-in-typescript#answer-32569711)
but i got error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: myArray.getFirst is not a function
  Evaluating http://localhost:8080/application/test/application/ts/bind_test
  Loading application/ts/bind_test
    at Object.execute (test.js:1733)
    at j (system.js:4)
    at E (system.js:4)
    at O (system.js:4)
    at system.js:5
```

**update**
it works when i add `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ArrayProxy.prototype);` after the super call in ArrayProxy's constructor. thanks to @Aluan Haddad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclassing built-ins is currently broken.

It is also extremely dangerous because when the code execute in es2015 compliant environments it will fail for functions like `Map`.

Use composition and avoid these techniques.

See here for reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work