# Typescript: Using array notation to get items from class

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

I have class called `Candles` and a class called `Candle`. `Candles` has a property `list` that contains an array of `Candle`.

```
class Candles
{
  public list: Array<Candle>;
}

class Candle
{
  public date: number;
  public high: number;
  public low: number;
  public open: number;
  public close: number;
  public volume: number;
}
```

I want `list` to encapsulate with the `Candles` class. For example,

```
const candles = new Candles();
candles[3] === candles.list[3];
```

I want `candles[3]` to return `candles.list[3]`

I also want to use map. Example:

```
candles.map(function(candle: Candle) {
    console.log(candle.high);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept and forward calls to inner list using ES6 [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get):

```
class Candles {
  public list: Candle[] = [];

  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, propertyKey) {
        console.log('getting ', propertyKey);
        if (propertyKey in target) {
          console.log('own property');
          return target[propertyKey]
        }

        console.log('forward to inner list');
        const property = target.list[propertyKey];
        if (typeof property === "function") {
          return property.bind(target.list);
        }

        return property;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

To inform the compiler that `Candles` can be used as an `Array` add following definition:

```
interface Candles extends Array<Candle> { }
```

And now all the array goodies (e.g. `push`, `foreach`, `map`...) can be applied to `Candles`:

```
const candles = new Candles();
candles.push({ low: 1 } as Candle);

console.log(candles[0] === candles.list[0]); //true
candles.forEach(c => console.log(c));
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Candle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20date%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20high%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20low%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20open%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20close%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20volume%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Candles%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20list%3A%20Candle%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Proxy(this%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20get(target%2C%20propertyKey)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('getting%20'%2C%20propertyKey)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(propertyKey%20in%20target)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('own%20property')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20target%5BpropertyKey%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('forward%20to%20inner%20list')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20property%20%3D%20target.list%5BpropertyKey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20property%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20property.bind(target.list)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20property%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Candles%20extends%20Array%3CCandle%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20candles%20%3D%20new%20Candles()%3B%0D%0Acandles.push(%7B%20low%3A%201%20%7D%20as%20Candle)%3B%0D%0Acandles.push(%7B%20low%3A%202%20%7D%20as%20Candle)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(candles%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20candles.list%5B0%5D)%3B%20%2F%2Ftrue%0D%0Acandles.forEach(c%20%3D%3E%20console.log(c))%3B) in playground.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the behavior of the indexing operation in Typescript because Javascript does not support this either. What you could do is create a type taht extends the standard array, as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000645/how-to-extend-native-javascript-array-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

What you want there is operator overloading. Typescript does not have support for it.

You can learn more about the reasoning why this is the case in the github issue threads:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2319
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5407

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
class Candles extends Array<Candle>
{
  constructor(candles: Array<Candle.Data>) {
    super(...candles.map((candle) => new Candle(candle as Candle.Data)));
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Candles, Object.assign(Array.prototype, Candles.prototype));
  }
}
```

I got rid of `list` and just extended `Array<Candle>`. I also added `Object.setPrototypeOf(Candles, Object.assign(Array.prototype, Candles.prototype));` to use the `Array` methods along with `Candles`'s method