# Create typescript extension for array of particular class type

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, typescript2.0

I know that i can create a basic Array extension, something like this, which works on all arrays, no matter what the type is within that array.

```
export {};

declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        isEmpty(): boolean;
    }
}

// determines if an array is empty, or if the contents of the items in the array are empty
Array.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    if (this.length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return this.some((c) => c != null && c != '');
    }
};
```

But i would like to create an extension for an array that only contains a particular object?  I have tried this, but gives error

```
import { MyObject } from './my-object';

export {};

declare global {
    interface Array<MyObject> {
        isEmpty(): boolean;
    }
}

// determines if an array is empty, or if the contents of the items in the array are empty
Array.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    if (this.length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return this.some((c) => c != null && c != '');
    }
};
```

I have tried to find out by looking [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) but i cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax.

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: You cannot do that. The generics part isn't being translated into javascript. In javascript there's no difference between arrays with different types of objects in them.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do?  As @NitzanTomer points out you can't specialize generics like that in TypeScript, where `Array<MyObject>` has a method `isEmpty()`, but `Array<string>` does not.  Depending on how you plan to use it, there are things that get you close.

#### Option 1: Extend `Array` prototype as you requested (not recommended)

The closest I can get to what you specifically asked for is to require [the `this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) of `isEmpty()` to be of type `Array<MyObject>`:

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    isEmpty(this: Array<MyObject>): boolean;
  }
}

// note the error below
Array.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  if (this.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return this.some((c) => c != null &&
      c != '' // error! c has to be MyObject, not string
    );
  }
};
```

(As an aside, your implementation of `isEmpty()` has an error when you compare an array element, now required to be `MyObject`, to a `string` value. The good news is that TypeScript is alerting you of this so you can fix it.)

You can now go ahead and call `isEmpty()` on arrays of `MyObject`:

```
declare let myObject1: MyObject;
declare let myObject2: MyObject;
const arrayOfMyObject: MyObject[] = [myObject1, myObject2];
arrayOfMyObject.isEmpty(); // okay
```

Now, the `isEmpty()` method *exists* on all arrays, but trying to call it on an array of a different type will give you an error:

```
const arrayOfStrings: string[] = ['a', 'b'];
arrayOfStrings.isEmpty();  // error, string is not MyObject
```

So that might work for you.

That being said, extending native prototypes like `Array` is [almost always considered a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/2887218).

---

#### Option 2: Extend selected `Array` instances with new method

A better idea would be to create a brand new class with the extra method, or to take individual `Array` instances and add the method to them without polluting the `Array` prototype.  Here's a way to do the latter:

```
interface MyObjectArray<T extends MyObject> extends Array<T>{ 
  isEmpty(): boolean;
}

const isEmpty = function(this: Array<MyObject>) {
  if (this.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return this.some((c) => c != null &&
      c != '' // error!  c is MyObject, not string
    );
  }
};

function toMyObjectArray<T extends MyObject>(arr: Array<T>): MyObjectArray<T> {
  const ret = arr as MyObjectArray<T>;
  ret.isEmpty = isEmpty.bind(ret);
  return ret;
}
```

Now we have a new interface called `MyObjectArray` which includes the extra method.  And if you have an existing instance of `MyObject[]`, you can convert it to `MyObjectArray` using the `toMyObjectArray()` function, which adds the `isEmpty()` method to it.  Then you can use it like this:

```
declare let myObject1: MyObject;
declare let myObject2: MyObject;
const arrayOfMyObject = [myObject1, myObject2];
arrayOfMyObject.isEmpty(); // error, no such method
const myObjectArray = toMyObjectArray(arrayOfMyObject); // convert
myObjectArray.isEmpty(); // okay

// can't convert an array of anything else
const arrayOfStrings = toMyObjectArray(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

There's an extra step of calling a conversion function every time you need to use `isEmpty()`, which might make this less desirable for you.

---

#### Option 3: Use standalone `isEmpty()` function, not method

In fact, if you are not going to mess with `Array.prototype`, and you have to call a function on the array instance, you might as well just skip the extra interface and use a standalone `isEmpty()` instead of bothering with methods:

```
const isMyObjectArrayEmpty = function(arr: Array<MyObject>) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return arr.some((c) => c != null &&
      c != '' // error!  c is MyObject, not string
    );
  }
};
    
declare let myObject1: MyObject;
declare let myObject2: MyObject;
const arrayOfMyObject = [myObject1, myObject2];
isMyObjectArrayEmpty(arrayOfMyObject); // okay

const arrayOfStrings = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
isMyObjectArrayEmpty(arrayOfStrings); // error
```

---

Those are the options as I see them.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with your first option. I've strongly typed everything and then I'm not able to use the newly defined function on array of other type than the one I've defined. So it's ok. Thanks a lot :) :) :)

Comment: @Nicolas, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) for some discussion about what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend an array for a particular type using this method. Typescript uses generic type erasure, so at runtime there is no way to distinguish between `Array<A>` and `Array<B>`. 
You could create a derived array type that adds the required methods, sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000645/how-to-extend-native-javascript-array-in-typescript), but you would have to new up that class instead of creating simple arrays with `[]`

Comment: Runtime erasure is not the issue here : we would just like to know *at compile time* that the extension method can be called on an array of `MyObject` but not on an array of any other type.