# TypeScript online compiler _extends fails (doesn't actually extend)

Tags: typescript, class, prototype

Try out [this link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20ExtArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20log()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20ExtArray(1%2C2%2C3)%0D%0Aa.log()%0D%0A) which includes following TS class that extends another class:

```
class ExtArray<T> extends Array<T> { 
    log() { 
        console.log(this)
    }
}

var a = new ExtArray(1,2,3)
a.log()
```

`a.log` should definitely exist, also, TS is able to compile that. However, the JS output fails to invoke ExtArray.prototype.log:

```
VM107:22 Uncaught TypeError: a.log is not a function
    at <anonymous>:22:3
```

The output:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var ExtArray = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(ExtArray, _super);
    function ExtArray() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    ExtArray.prototype.log = function () {
        console.log(this);
    };
    return ExtArray;
}(Array));
var a = new ExtArray(1, 2, 3);
a.log();
```

**What is wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

<del>To start with, I strongly feel you've found a bug - please report it to typescript issues.</del> (see jcalz's comment).

As for what's causing this, there's a technical explanation.

The `Array` function is "special" in various ways, and one of these is that the function behaves identically whether you invoke it directly or as a constructor ([link](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array-objects)):

> When **Array** is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it also creates and initializes a new Array object. Thus the function call **Array(…)** is equivalent to the object creation expression **new Array(…)** with the same arguments.

Since TypeScript assumes that `_super.apply(this, arguments)` will return `this` but instead a new instance is returned, your `a` variable actually holds a pure `Array` instance, and not an `ExtArray`.

By the way, that special behavior I mentioned about `Array` is also true for other native objects, for example, `RegExp`.

---

As for `Array(...)` itself, it is meant to handle a `super(...)` call correctly, but since it is invoked indirectly via `apply`, it doesn't receive the correct `new.target` and that doesn't work.

A potential solution to this by the compiler might be to call `super(arguments)` or to reflect it with `Reflect.construct(this, arguments)`.

Comment: I don't think this needs a new issue.  There is [an existing issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7340) reporting this.  The Playground is not as [configurable](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13673) as people would like; it targets ES5, and [you can't](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) extend the Array constructor without using ES2015-and-up class syntax.

Comment: @jcalz - good catch, and I'm honestly perplexed as to why this issue is closed without resolution. I could think of a workaround (hacky, but should work) or at the very minimum output a warning message to console (`if(_super.apply(...) !== this) { console.error('Unsupported base class...'); }`).

Comment: @Amit Neither `super(arguments)` nor `Reflect.construct(this, arguments)` compile under TypeScript. `super` has to be called (directly, nominally) and `arguments` of type `IArguments` violates my types.

Comment: @ducin - that part of my answer was confusing. I didn't mean a solution we developers could use, I meant what might work for the compiler. Edited answer accordingly...

Comment: @Amit no problem ;) thanks for your effort. The problem is the _potential_ solutions from last paragraph (`super(arguments)`, `Reflect.construct(this, arguments)`) don't compile. BTW see a working solution below, I think it's the most accurate one - addressing the explanation you gave)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [working solution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20ExtArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(...args)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(...args)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.setPrototypeOf(this%2C%20ExtArray.prototype)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20log()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20ExtArray(1%2C2%2C3)%0D%0Aa.log()%0D%0A), basing on [another SO thread solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32569711/769384). The trick is to add this line:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ExtArray.prototype);
```

to the constructor. All looks like this:

```
class ExtArray<T> extends Array<T> { 
    constructor(...args) { 
        super(...args)
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ExtArray.prototype);
    }
    log() { 
        console.log(this)
    }
}

var a = new ExtArray(1,2,3)
a.log()
```