# Use Datejs in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How would you tell TypeScript to use Datejs as `Date` instead of the builtin `Date` object?

I tried adding a reference to the js file and declaring Date as type `any` i.e. `declare var Date: any;` but this did nothing to fix the error.

**EDIT:**
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701732/typescript-augmenting-built-in-types) question, but it talks about specifying a method to include.  I'm wondering if it's possible to leave it open ended and simply turn off type checking for Date;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a way to take an existing variable with a type (`Date` in this case) and turn it in to an `any`.

The best option would be to extend the `Date` interface with the new methods from datejs. Hopefully at some point someone will do this and upload it to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

Two workarounds you could do:

```
var Date2 = <any>Date;
// Use Date2 anywhere you would use Date
```

The other workaround would be to just modify `lib.d.ts` to declare `Date` as `any`. Obviously this will have side effects everywhere, but would work.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll try the `Date2` method.  I had tried to write an interface declaration for only the methods that I needed to get started, but I'm doing something incorrectly I believe.  Do you happen to know what that interface declaration would look like?

Comment: It's likely you were hitting the bug where extensions of things declared in lib.d.ts don't work well in Visual Studio. The interface would just look like a normal interface declaration.

Comment: Would you have to `extend` `Date` or simply `interface Date{}`?  Also the `var Date2` worked great so ty.

Comment: e.g. `interface Date { getTimeSinceYesterday(): number; }`

Comment: It's on DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/datejs

Answer (score 7):

To get you started with extending the native date, it would look like this:

```
interface DateIs {
    monday(): bool;
    // ctd...
    january(): bool;
    // ctd...
    weekday(): bool;
}

interface DateAdd {
    days(): Date;
    months(): Date;
    // ctd...
}

interface Date {
    parse(date: string): Date;
    today(): Date;
    next(): Date;
    last(): Date;
    monday(): Date;
    // ctd...
    january(): Date;
    // ctd...
    addDays(days: number): Date;
    addMonths(months: number): Date;
    add(quantity: number): DateAdd;
    is(): DateIs;
}
```

With this example, you could continue to add the functions you use, I have put in one month as an example so you could fill in february() and also the short jan() variations as you see fit!

Answer (score 1):

Install the package 'datejs.typescript.definitelytyped' from nuget

http://www.nuget.org/packages/datejs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Add a reference to the type file.   In a global script file declare a global variable, or in a class declare either a private static member variable or simply a local variable, assigning as shown in the code below.

```
/// <reference path="typings/datejs/datejs.d.ts" />
var DateJs: IDateJSStatic = <any>Date;
```

I'm currently writing SPA applications so I use a global variable as shown in the code example.