# How to get TypeScript language service to not complain about global types?

Tags: typescript

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12701878/65387) about how to extend built-in types, but it only tells half the story. How do we tell TypeScript where to find our global definitions?

I've created a file,

#### src/cssom.d.ts

```
interface HTMLElement {
    computedStyleMap(): any
}
```

And then tried including it with `include` (not sure if this is the best option or not):

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "files": [
        "src/index"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

But my VS Code still complains:

[image]

Even though it compiles without error or warnings via [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader).

So what do I have to do to get the language service to behave? What's the best way to configure tsconfig to read all my `*.d.ts` files?

---

Adding

```
///<reference path="cssom.d.ts"/>
```

To the top of the file satisfies both the compiler and the language service, but I *really* don't want to add these `<reference>`s everywhere since I'm extending a built-in/global type.

Comment: Open root of your ReactApp. It should have properly configured tsconfig.json Otherwise follow this guide https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Comment: @zoonman The webpack part is working fine. It's the TS language service that doesn't know what's up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tsx file shown in the screenshot is not part of the project defined by your tsconfig.json because it isn't referenced by either the `files` or the files matching the `includes`.  Your `"files"` should probably be changed to `["src/index.tsx"]`; I tested and the extension does make a difference.

Comment: Oh my.... I think you're right! I just assumed I was allowed to leave off the extension because it was compiling. But I guess that's because of my webpack config, not my tsconfig. That explain it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the [`"typeRoots"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) tsconfig compiler option. I think you can solve this by including your file in the `typeRoots` array

```
"typeRoots": [
  "src/cssom.d.ts"
]
```

Or you can simply include a path to a folder in the typeRoots array to include all types in that folder.

#### Update:

Incidentally, I only know this because the [`typescript-starter`](https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter) project automatically configures a default typeRoots folder for you and explains how to use it. Very helpful.

#### Update 2:

I suppose it's worth noting that the typescript documentation specifically says the `typeRoots` option should include a list of folder paths, so it's possible pointing to a specific `*.d.ts` file wouldn't work.

#### Update 3:

As @mpen pointed out, including your own `typeRoots` will overwrite the default `node_modules/@types` typeRoot. So you'll want to specifically include that typeRoot as well:

i.e. `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"]`

Comment: If I use `typeRoots` it'll stop checking `node_modules/@types` as far as I'm aware. I want to retain the defaults too

Comment: @mpen Good point, in my project I have `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"]`

Comment: Tried it. Now both the language service *and* the compiler are complaining. I *think* typeRoots expects *modules* in there judging by this typescript-starter example. I don't have a module, I'm extending a built-in type.